# Expand an image in gridview when clicked in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am implementing a `GridView` which contains images.
I want to expand an image to occupy the whole row when it's clicked as shown in the images below.
I also want to show a button when the image is expanded so the user can take an action similar to how the ESPN app does that.

How can I achieve this?

[image: First Image]           **---->**      [image: Second Image]

Answer (score 0):

Surround your layout with a relative layout. Create a layout and a button inside it outside grid layout/inside relative layout. Set it's initial visibility to gone and match it's height, width to row you want it to encompass. Then in the onclick of the image set the layouts view to visible and it's button. Perhaps not perfect but it has the added benefit of allowing scrolling of your gridview while showing the big image you want.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution but the thing is when you select an image it will take space always. What happens when a user accidentally selects an image? In that case that top portion will stay there reducing the scrolling space in bottom.

Comment: if previously hidden image is visible allow onClick of image that reduces to original size.