# Android Listview multiple buttons click

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-studio

My issue is regarding listview multiple buttons click. e.g. my list view contain 3 rows and each row contains 3 buttons. when i click on first button in first row it changes color in last row first button

[please check image you will know the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHaAp.png)

I have tried to solve it using button tags, view holder, tried to assign position to button but still nothing happened

```
public class ViewOrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context mcontext;
    ArrayList<ViewOrder> view_order_array = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    String currentTime;
    String ord_id;
    public Button accept_btn, pickup_btn, delieverd_btn, order_view, rest_address, cust_address;
    GPSTracker gps;
    String latitude, longitude;
    private static int ipos;
    boolean[] buttonState;
    AlertDialog alert;
    View view;
    OrdersFragment ord_frag;
    ViewOrderAdapter view_order_adapter1;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyApp_Settings";
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    SharedPreferences prefs;

    public ViewOrderAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<ViewOrder> view_order_array) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mcontext = context;
        prefs = mcontext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, mcontext.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.view_order_array = view_order_array;
        buttonState = new boolean[view_order_array.size()];
        gps = new GPSTracker(mcontext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return view_order_array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return view_order_array.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_single_row, parent, false);
        view = convertView;

        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        final ViewOrder v_ordr = view_order_array.get(position);
        TextView cname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_name_view);
        cname.setText(v_ordr.getRestaurant());
        TextView caddr = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_address_view);
        caddr.setText(v_ordr.getRaddress());

        accept_btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_accept_btn);
        pickup_btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_pickup_btn);
        delieverd_btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_delievery_btn);

        accept_btn.setTag(position);
        pickup_btn.setTag(position);
        delieverd_btn.setTag(position);

        order_view = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_info);
        rest_address = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rest_addrs);
        cust_address = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cstom_addrs);
        int id = Integer.parseInt(view_order_array.get(position).getId());


        accept_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                AppConstants.btn_id = view_order_array.get(position).getId();
                String id = AppConstants.btn_id;
                //accept_btn.setId(position);

                buttonState[position] = false;

                String token = AppPreferences.getSharedPrefValue(mcontext, AppConstants.auth);
                ShowMessagesDialogsUtitly.showProgressDialog(mcontext);
                RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
                requestParams.put("k", token);
                requestParams.put("id", id);   //order id
                requestParams.put("status", Integer.toString(1));
                requestParams.put("time", currentTime);
                requestParams.put("page", "send");

                HttpUtils.httpPostRequest(AppConstants.BASE_URL, requestParams, new HttpResponseCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleteHttpResponse(String whichUrl, String jsonResponse) {
                        ShowMessagesDialogsUtitly.hideProgressDialog();

                        if (jsonResponse != null) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonResponseObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                                if (jsonResponseObj.getInt("status") == 1) {
                                    accept_btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

                                    Intent n = new Intent(mcontext, Order.class);
                                    mcontext.startActivity(n);
                                    ((Activity)mcontext).finish();

                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Order progress error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                AppUtilites.printStackTrace(e);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, AppConstants.SERVER_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        pickup_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AppConstants.btn_id = view_order_array.get(position).getId();
                String id = AppConstants.btn_id;
                String token = AppPreferences.getSharedPrefValue(mcontext, AppConstants.auth);
                pickup_btn.setId(position);

                ShowMessagesDialogsUtitly.showProgressDialog(mcontext);
                RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
                requestParams.put("k", token);
                requestParams.put("id", id);   //order id
                requestParams.put("status", Integer.toString(2));
                requestParams.put("time", currentTime);
                requestParams.put("page", "send");

                HttpUtils.httpPostRequest(AppConstants.BASE_URL, requestParams, new HttpResponseCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleteHttpResponse(String whichUrl, String jsonResponse) {
                        ShowMessagesDialogsUtitly.hideProgressDialog();

                        if (jsonResponse != null) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonResponseObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

                                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Order accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Order order not accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                AppUtilites.printStackTrace(e);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, AppConstants.SERVER_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        delieverd_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppConstants.btn_id = view_order_array.get(position).getId();
                String id = AppConstants.btn_id;
                String token = AppPreferences.getSharedPrefValue(mcontext, AppConstants.auth);
                delieverd_btn.setId(position);

                ShowMessagesDialogsUtitly.showProgressDialog(mcontext);
                RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
                requestParams.put("k", token);
                requestParams.put("id", id);   //order id
                requestParams.put("status", Integer.toString(3));
                requestParams.put("time", currentTime);
                requestParams.put("page", "send");

                HttpUtils.httpPostRequest(AppConstants.BASE_URL, requestParams, new HttpResponseCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleteHttpResponse(String whichUrl, String jsonResponse) {
                        ShowMessagesDialogsUtitly.hideProgressDialog();

                        if (jsonResponse != null) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonResponseObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

                                if (jsonResponseObj.getInt("status") == 1) {                        
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Order order not delievered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                AppUtilites.printStackTrace(e);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, AppConstants.SERVER_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        order_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_view_lay, (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.order_view_lay_id));
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
                builder.setView(layout);
                alert = builder.create();

                TextView order_id = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.order_no);
                order_id.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getOid());
                TextView rest_name = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.rstarnt_name);
                rest_name.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getRestaurant());

                TextView quantity = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                quantity.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getOid());
                TextView item = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.item);
                item.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getMenu());
                TextView price = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.price);
                price.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getAmount());

                TextView subtotal = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.sub_total);
                subtotal.setText("XXXX");
                TextView total = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.total);
                total.setText("XXXX");

                Button ok = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.ok_popup_order_view_btn);
                ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alert.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });
        rest_address.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_addr_lay, (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.rest_addr_lay_id));
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
                builder.setView(layout);
                alert = builder.create();

                TextView r_name = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.rst_name_popup);
                r_name.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getRestaurant());
                TextView r_add = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.rst_addr_popup);
                r_add.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getRaddress());
                TextView r_phone = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.rst_phone_popup);
                r_phone.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getRestaurant());

                Button map = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.map_to_restaurant_popup);
                map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                            latitude = gps.getLatitude() + "";
                            longitude = gps.getLongitude() + "";

                            AppConstants.Latitude = latitude.toString();
                            AppConstants.Longitude = longitude.toString();

                            double lat = Double.valueOf(latitude);
                            double lon = Double.valueOf(longitude);
                            gps.getCompleteAddressString(lat, lon);

                            AppConstants.Address_To = view_order_array.get(position).getRaddress();
                            String addr = AppConstants.Address_To;
                            gps.getLocationFromAddress(mcontext, addr);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, MapLayout.class);
                            mcontext.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            gps.showSettingsAlert();
                        }
                    }
                });

                Button map_dirct = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.directions_to_restaurant_popup);
                map_dirct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                            latitude = gps.getLatitude() + "";
                            longitude = gps.getLongitude() + "";

                            AppConstants.Latitude = latitude.toString();
                            AppConstants.Longitude = longitude.toString();

                            double lat = Double.valueOf(latitude);
                            double lon = Double.valueOf(longitude);
                            gps.getCompleteAddressString(lat, lon);

                            AppConstants.Address_To = view_order_array.get(position).getRaddress();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, MapLayout.class);
                            mcontext.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            gps.showSettingsAlert();
                        }
                    }
                });

                Button ok = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.ok_popup_raddr_btn);
                ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alert.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });
        cust_address.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_addr_lay, (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.cust_addr_lay_id));
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
                builder.setView(layout);
                alert = builder.create();

                TextView c_name = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.cst_name_popup);
                c_name.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getCustomer());
                TextView c_add = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.cst_addr_popup);
                c_add.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getCaddress());
                TextView c_phone = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.cst_phone_popup);
                c_phone.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getCphone());
                TextView order_inst = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.cst_order_inst_popup);
                order_inst.setText(view_order_array.get(position).getInstruction());

                Button map = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.map_to_customer_popup);
                map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                            latitude = gps.getLatitude() + "";
                            longitude = gps.getLongitude() + "";

                            AppConstants.Latitude = latitude.toString();
                            AppConstants.Longitude = longitude.toString();

                            double lat = Double.valueOf(latitude);
                            double lon = Double.valueOf(longitude);
                            gps.getCompleteAddressString(lat, lon);

                            AppConstants.Address_To = view_order_array.get(position).getCaddress();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, MapLayout.class);
                            mcontext.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            gps.showSettingsAlert();
                        }
                    }
                });

                Button map_direct = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.directions_to_customer_popup);
                map_direct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                            latitude = gps.getLatitude() + "";
                            longitude = gps.getLongitude() + "";

                            AppConstants.Latitude = latitude.toString();
                            AppConstants.Longitude = longitude.toString();

                            double lat = Double.valueOf(latitude);
                            double lon = Double.valueOf(longitude);
                            gps.getCompleteAddressString(lat, lon);

                            AppConstants.Address_To = view_order_array.get(position).getCaddress();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, MapLayout.class);
                            mcontext.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            gps.showSettingsAlert();
                        }
                    }
                });

                Button ok = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.ok_popup_caddr_btn);
                ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alert.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use ViewHolder pattern..
In above code what happening is last added button's color is updating it is natural...

Comment: what is that? You sad i want change color in same row. And image that your example, changing same row color? Are you sure what you want to ask?

Comment: Hi Please try to implement my edited answer with view holder pattern in listview.

Comment: It worked for same problem in gridview item click , Let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple answer:

find your button view by the tag you have set.

```
((Button) convertView.findViewWithTag(position)).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

You are encountering this problem because the last accept_btn object your adapter is holding is the last view object it created.

Therefore you are on the right track by setting a tag on the button. But then you have to retrieve that view by the tag.
Let me know if this is helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. However, the next problem he will encounter will be that all the buttons set with the same TAG will change colors. From there he can figure how to set different tag names for each button. Also, This adapter can have more problems in the future but this answer will help him figure out his initial question.

Answer (score 0):

I have written answer for same problem in gridview [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845314/how-to-detect-the-imageview-of-clicked-position-in-gridview/39845784#39845784). You can use same trick to solve this issue.
// Brief idea

You can implement your own custom OnClickListener and you can associate id/tag/position for each onclick of each item of listview.

```
yourBtn.setOnclickListener(new BtnClick(position, btnid));
```

Custom OnclickListener:

```
 Class BtnClick View.OnClickListener
 {
     int position;
     int btnId;
     Public BtnClick(int position, int id)
    {
        this.position = position;'
        this.btnId = btnId;
    }
    @Override
    public onClick(View v)
    { 
      // You can add logic here for each item clicked using position and id of each item you passed in constructor
    }

}
```